# trying to dynamically name pandas dataframes while reading from a folder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analytics, data-cleaning

I'm trying name pandas dataframes while reading them from a local folder. Note that they have to be separate dataframes and I have not intention of concatenating or merging them. but after trying to run the below code it's just returning the same dataframe for all the dataframe names.
Thanks for looking.

import os

import pandas as pd

from glob import glob

files = glob('*.csv') # all the files

'''
['players_15.csv',
'players_16.csv',
'players_17.csv',
'players_18.csv',
'players_19.csv',
'players_20.csv',
'players_21.csv',
'players_22.csv']
'''

df_names = [f'fifa_{year}' for year in range(15,23)] # the names they should be

'''
['fifa_15',
'fifa_16',
'fifa_17',
'fifa_18',
'fifa_19',
'fifa_20',
'fifa_21',
'fifa_22']
'''

for file in files:

```
for name in df_names:

    name = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Comment: You're only reading the files. Why would that change them on disk?

Comment: You could create a dictionary, where each key is a name, with a dataframe as its value, e.g. `d={}; d[name]=pd.read.csv(…)`. What you’re doing right now is re-assigning `name` on every iteration, which won’t keep a dataframe in memory after you exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using pathlib and create a dictionary of dataframes:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


files = Path("path/to/files/").glob("players*.csv")
dfs = {f"fifa_{x.stem.split('_')[1]}": pd.read_csv(x) for x in files}
```